# zsh process taking 95% of my CPU

Tags: macos, zsh

When opening my activity monitor, I have a zsh process taking all my CPU. Is it normal? I have [iTerm](http://iterm2.com/) and [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) installed but I don't expect it as a normal behaviour.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this reproducible for every new zsh session? If so, start with no zshrc files and narrow the problem down. Or is it only one process which has gone mad?

Comment: I restarted my system and the process was no here anymore. It appears again once I started *iTerm* but with very low CPU (0.25%).

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146919/zsh-using-100-of-cpu-during-iwork-install/187153#187153.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I encounter this problem a lot, too. It always involves `installd`, and most importantly, with `installd` installing/updating Apple apps, like iWork (IIRC it's iWork exclusive; at least I've yet to encounter an occurrence with a third party app).

I believe it has nothing to do with iTerm2 or oh-my-zsh (although I use both, too). What I believe is that this is a shell compatibility issue — Apple's installer script calls your default shell, probably

```
$SHELL -c command...
```

It was tested on `bash` but not `zsh`, so when `zsh` gets called this way, subtle shell compatibility issues arise. When you inspect the offending process (Activity Monitor unfortunately, AFAIK, doesn't show you the full commands; I use `htop` for this, and you may well use `ps` or whatever), you will see things like

```
zsh -c defaults delete com.apple.helpd com.apple.helpd.sdmMapsCreated
```

which backs my guess (well, my guess was actually derived from these observations, to be precise).* Therefore, the solution is simply run the command yourself, in this case

```
defaults delete com.apple.helpd com.apple.helpd.sdmMapsCreated
```

Then you kill the offending processes. `installd` automatically moves on (probably to the next stuck process like this). After multiple rounds of grinding you'll find the installation finished successfully. I know this is annoying, but this is the only way I found to work (reliably).

---

* It is actually beyond me how `zsh -c` gets stuck on things like `defaults delete`. Not sure if it's with my environment. (I've put GNU coreutils and alike in front of BSD stuff in my PATH, but I'm pretty sure I never messed with `default`.) Maybe `default` internally use BSD utils? But again, I can run the same command in my terminal with zsh, either interactively or non-interactively, just fine. This is really baffling (the solution above is not affected). Any input is welcome.

Comment: What a nice analysis! Thank you very much I will try that as soon as the problem arise again :-)

Comment: The problem didn't occurs again but I really appreciated your help!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! To show the full process command line with standard `ps` tool just run `ps uaxwww | grep zsh` then: 1. check for what's hogging the CPU; 2. execute it manually; 3. kill the process; 4. repeat

Comment: The `-c` compatibility analysis sounds right, though I can't understand either why that would get stuck, instead of just failing and returning. I'm trying to reproduce this myself. Where did you install the GNU coreutils from? And by any chance are you using a Homebrew or other non-default `zsh`?

Comment: @AndrewJanke I don't know why, and I think one should probably need to read the package scripts to figure out, which I never bothered to do. My coreutils is from Homebrew (MacPorts back in the days), and my Zsh has been the stock Zsh for the most part (I recently switched to brewed 5.0.7, but the issue here has been around well before that).

Answer (score 0):

I regularly have the same issue and it's always related to the installd process, updating an AppStore application. Killing first installd and then the zsh process helps (but disables the AppStore's functionality until it's restarted).